# Repeated measures MANOVA returning Pillai greater than 1

Tags: r, repeated-measures, manova

I am attempting to investigate the presence of a multivariate main effect using a repeated measures MANOVA.

I couldn't figure out how to include a table to share some data so I have included a screenshot below. I have removed the names for confidentiality but these data are all from one participant with a total of 27 participants (i.e., 189 rows x 22 columns).

[image]

The aim is to understand if foot position (7 levels acting as a repeated measure) has a multivariate main effect on the 19 dependant variables (X_moment to Z_grf).

My code to run the MANOVA is outlined below. The issue I am facing is that the Pillai value is returning as 2.9455 and should lie between 0-1.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening or where I might being going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
summary(manova(cbind(
  X_moment, Y_moment, Z_moment, X_angle, Y_angle, Z_angle,  X_power, Y_power, Z_power, X_velocity, 
Y_velocity, Z_velocity, X_excursion, Y_excursion,  Z_excursion, Z_grf, Z_grf_time, Z_loading_rate , height) 
~ jump + Error(name), data=data))
```